# "Form des Hin-und-Her?" vs. "Form des Hin-und-Hers?"

Tags: grammar-identification

Sagt und schreibt man

> Eine Form des Hin-und-Her?

oder

> Eine Form des Hin-und-Hers?

Muss am Ende des Ausdrucks *Hin-und-Her* ein *s* stehen?

Comment: beides geht, der Rest ist Stilfrage.

Comment: [https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hin_und_Her](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hin_und_Her)

Answer (score 1):

Beides ist richtig, wie der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hin_und_Her) bestätigt. Dass hier das "s" optional ist, ist unter dem Stichwort "Tendenz zur Monoflexion" zu finden:

Bei bestimmten Nomen darf auch standardsprachlich das "s" beim Genitiv fehlen, wenn das "s" schon bei der Präposition davor ist, hauptsächlich nach "des", "dieses", etc. Laut [Grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/korpusgrammatik/5052):

> Nach Artikelwörtern mit Genitiv-s, zum Beispiel des, dieses, eines, jedes wird das Genitiv-s oft weggelassen.
> Der durch den morphosyntaktischen Kontext bedingte Wegfall der Genitivendung erfolgt allerdings nicht generell, sondern ist nur bei bestimmten Teilklassen von Nomen zu beobachten (vgl. auch bereits Appel 1941 zu "Substantiven mit labilem s").1 Dabei handelt es sich primär um Substantive, die aufgrund ihrer semantisch-pragmatischen/kommunikativen Funktion, ihrer Herkunft oder ihrer morphologischen Eigenschaften eine Sonderrolle im Flexionssystem einnehmen, insbesondere Eigennamen, eigennamenähnliche Substantive (z.B. Wochentage oder Bezeichnungen für Produkte bzw. Stilepochen), das erste Glied sog. Paarformeln und anderer Koordinationsstrukturen (des Sturm und Drangs, Peter und Marias Wohnung), Fremdwörter, Substantivierungen (insbes. Konversionen wie z.B. des Gestern, Gegenüber, Hier und Jetzt) und Abkürzungen.

"Hin und Her" gehört hier zu der Klasse der Konversionen, wo ein Ausdruck wie ein Nomen behandelt wird. Im Artikel steht noch viel zur möglichen Gründen dazu. Ein möglicher Grund ist, dass in "Hin und Hers" nicht mehr so deutlich ist, dass es eigentlich "(Hin+und+Her)+s" ist und nicht "Hin+und+Hers".

Das fehlende "s" beim Nomen ist Teil eines größeren Phänomens, das bei http://gallmann.uni-jena.de/Wort/Wort_NP_Genitiv_Besonderheiten.pdf als Genitivregel genannt wird: Einerseits kann eine Phrase nur "richtig" Genitiv sein, wenn

> (i) Die NP enthält mindestens ein Artikelwort oder Adjektiv mit Flexions‐
> endung als primären Merkmalsträger.
> (ii) Die NP enthält mindestens ein Wort mit Endung ‐es/‐s oder ‐er.

Andererseits hat das Deutsche die Tendenz, eben nur ein Wort mit "-s" or "-er" zu haben, weil eines schon für Genitiv reicht.